# IIS ARR Reverse Proxy Works Until SSO Is Turned On

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, arr

I am new to using IIS and the reverse proxy feature (ARR V3.0).

I have everything working correctly until a backend SSO authentication is enabled with the application.

The feature works from the IIS reverse proxy server if I go straight to the back end application but it fails when you try to authenticate thru the reverse proxy from the outside.

Flow is something like this when SSO is disabled:

Public User --> Public URL --> IIS/ARR --> Authentication --> Application Is Presented to user for login. Everything works. Again this is a single web server in the back end used for logon.

Flow is something like this when SSO is enabled:

Public User --> Public URL --> IIS/ARR --> Authentication --> Application Server --> SSO Application server --> IIS/ARR presents the back end (internal) SSO server name with DNS error. This is where the second server handling SSO is thrown into the mix.

The error displayed in a browser shows the internal server name in URL
(https://em004tcss066.xxxx.xxxx.xxx:8443/) with a DNS error (expected since the external DNS records do not contain the internal server names. I do see the redirectToSSO message above the address bar as it does that in the background but eventually times out with DNS error.

Current rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                 <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_REFERER" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://em004tcweb062.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx:3000/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Base, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://em004tcweb062.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx:3000/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="https{R:1}://xxxxxteamcentertraining.xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I know this is an issue with ARR, but I am not sure what rule needs added/modified to resolve it?

Comment: At least people know that SSO solutions like Azure AD work flawlessly with IIS ARR. So, before concluding "this is an issue with ARR" a lot of further digging is required. Can you edit the question to include more info on "IIS/ARR presents the back end (internal) SSO server name with DNS error"? What exactly does the error look like?

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, you can try to enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr), it will provide the key error and warning.

Comment: Here is the completed flow from a user login:  User request --> Webserver --> Redirect to SSO server --> Redirect back to Webserver --> User presented with application when successful. Does that help?

Comment: No, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.